# How to perform Two-proportion Z test on items in a row of a dataframe and append the p value to the dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, chi-squared

I am using R, and have data in a dataframe.

Each row of the dataframe has data on an urban/rural basis, and a two proportion Z-Test to compare the rates between urban and rural populations.

df

```
State     UrbanPop     RuralPop     UrbanCases   RuralCases
AL         1000         250          200          50
AK         500          50           500          75
```

The idea is to get a Two proportion Z test from the data in row A and from row B independently to compare urban/rural within each State.

What I have tried is

```
df$P_Values <- apply(df,1,function(x) prop.test(x = c(df$UrbanPop, df$UrbanCases), n = c(df$RuralPop, df$RuralCases))$p.value)
```

I get a warning that the "Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect" for each row, and all the p values appended to the dataframe are equal to zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `x`and `n` wrong: `x` is "a vector of counts of successes"; that would match your `*Cases`, whereas `n` is the number of trials; that would correspond to your `*Pop`. If you re-assign the vectors for `x` and `n`, the code works:

```
df$P_Values <- apply(df, 1, function(x) prop.test(n = c(df$UrbanPop, df$UrbanCases), 
                                                  x = c(df$RuralPop, df$RuralCases))$p.value)

df
  UrbanPop RuralPop UrbanCases RuralCases             P_Values
1     1000      250        200         50 0.000000000001119084
2      500       50        500         75 0.000000000001119084
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the p values are all the same.  Is it calculating by adding the columns?

Comment: After reading up on the prop.test it seems you need to compare the cases against the population totals. So you could first calculate the population total (rural + urban): `df$TotalPop <- df$UrbanPop + df$RuralPop`. That total represents `n`